# Symfony2 - 2 firewalls, 1 login

Tags: security, symfony, firewall

**Question:** I want to create an admin part in my Symfony2 website that would be available only to users with a ROLE_ADMIN

I don't know if I should create a new firewall or use acces controls. I tried to do both together but the admin part is still accessible to all users.

Currently all the website is under secured area firewall and pages i want available to anonymous are freed with access control.

Here is my security.yml

```
security:
    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email
        my_facebook_provider:
            id: my_user.facebook_provider 

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        login:
            pattern:  ^/login$
            security: false
            context: login

        admin:
            pattern: /admin/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                check_path: /login_check
                login_path: /login
            anonymous: ~

        secured_area:
             pattern: ^/
            anonymous: ~
            form_login:
                 login_path: /login
                check_path: /login_check
                default_target_path: tk_group_homepage
                provider: fos_userbundle
                remember_me: true
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            remember_me:
                key: %secret%
                lifetime: 31536000 # 365 days in seconds
            fos_facebook:
                app_url: "%api_facebook_name%"
                server_url: "%api_facebook_server%"
                check_path: /login_facebook_check   
                default_target_path: tk_user_homepage
                provider: my_facebook_provider
            logout:
                path:   fos_user_security_logout
                target: fos_user_security_login
                invalidate_session: false
            context: login

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/new, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/invitation, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/(subscribe|about|blog|press|contact), role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

I am also thinking about checking in the controller is the user has an admin role and throwing an exception if not, as my admin part is only one page currently. But I do not know if it is best practice and it could be a problem if i want to extend my admin part.

And I do not want to create a new user provider as we would be only 2 admins.

Thank you very much,
Jules

Answer (score 2):

You should remove the `admin` firewall and rely on `access_control`; If you have admin login form under the `/admin/` URL, you of course will not be able to see it before logging in, so you should either use the `/login` form to sign in as admin, or modify your access_control:

```
   - { path: ^/admin/login/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
   - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

here is what official doc says about your situation:

> 1. Multiple firewalls don't share security context If you're using multiple firewalls and you authenticate against one firewall, you will
>      not be authenticated against any other firewalls automatically.
>      Different firewalls are like different security systems. To do this
>      you have to explicitly specify the same Firewall Context for different
>      firewalls. But usually for most applications, having one main firewall
>      is enough.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#book-security-common-pitfalls

You should read the whole `Common pitfalls` section

**If you would really really like to use different firewalls**, just do as the documentation states, and share the same firewall context beetween them. This is also described in the documentation:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html#reference-security-firewall-context

and here is a simple example:

```
    admin:
        (... other options ...)
        context: my_security_context

    secured_area:
        context: my_security_context
        (... other options ...)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the access control does not work for my case, and this is my question. putting - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN } does not prevent a normal user from accessing the /admin url.

Comment: what happens if you delete the trailing slash? So transform `^/admin/` to `^/admin`?

Answer (score 0):

The Access Control looks for the **first match**.

Because of that you need to put this line:

```
- { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Before this line:

```
- { path: ^/$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

If you do not, /admin/whatever matches the path *^/$* and needs no ROLE_ADMIN.